# Content grep in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

To fetch the content I have written the code below.

```
The paragraph continous here....................
................................................
TABLE1..
...........Text continuous...........  
......... Text continuous...........  
..........Text continuous...........  
........Text continuous...........  
........Text continuous...........  
........Text continuous...........google.co.inFrancisCo.  
The paragraph continous here....................  
................................................
```

The pattern that I need to match is "TABLEn ..... google.co.in". I coded the regex below but doesn't grep the pattern.

```
match = re.search(r'TABLE(\d+)((?:(?!google.co.in).)*)google.co.in', extractedtext, re.M)
if match:
    ful = match.group()
    print(f": {ful}")
    # Additional processing with 'ful' if needed
else:
    print("Not matched")
```

Someone could you please help me on this one.

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean. Is the intent to check if the domain occurs anywhere after TABLE in a multinine string? Just `.split()` on the domain name and if that succeeds, check if the zeroth element contains `"TABLE"`. If not, or if splitting fails to produce more than one element, the answer is no.

Comment: You want `re.S`, not `re.M`

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your hint Its working changed `re.S` instead of `re.M`.